# Помогите пожалуйста, не могу понять в чем ошибка

Tags: массивы, ассемблер

Ошибка "**Error** u1.asm(14) Operand types do not match"

```
model small
.stack 100h
.data
    Len equ 7
    sum db 0
    mas db 1,0,9,8,0,7,0
.code
start:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov cx,Len
    XOR ax,ax
    XOR si,si
    mov ax,sum
cycl:
    add al,mas[si]
    adc ah,0
    inc si
    loop cycl
exit:
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
end start
```

Answer (score 2):

В команде `mov ax, sum` операнды должны иметь одинаковый размер.

Регистр `ax` имеет размер `слово`. `sum` объявлена размером `байт`.

Объявите

```
sum dw 0
```